# why ffmpeg streaming speed slower than browser

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I am downloading a live streaming video using ffmpeg. If I watch it in browser the video is seamless. But when I download using ffmpeg it skips frames a lot. Frequently it shows `skipping * segments ahead, expired from playlists`. I found [this discussion](https://github.com/soimort/you-get/issues/1270) but no answer. It also noticed in windows network monitor the speed of chrome is a lot higher than ffmpeg. Why does that happen? How do I solve this? I used the following command for ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i <m3u8 url> -c copy out.ts
```